# Download javascript dynamically and execute it later

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am trying to optimize page loading time. And the only thing left is optimizing asset loading times. I have few assets and a library script.
Some of the assets are dependent to this library.

**Vendor Scripts**

- library.min.js
- vendor.min.js

**Bundle Scripts**

- page.bundle.js (dependent to library.min.js)
- play.min.js (dependent to vendor.min.js)
- gtm.min.js (dependent to library.min.js)

What I want to achieve is start loading all of these assets when page is fully loaded. As I am rendering everything at serverside, it is not a problem for me to delay user interactions. I just need to download `library.min.js` then `page.bundle.js` in the exact order but **when I need to**.

I tried few things, but I just couldn't start downloading and execute it in right order. Currently I am planning to use xhr and `eval` content when I need it. But I am not sure if this is the right way. There are more questions to ask when using this method. Caching etc.

Can someone give me an idea how can I split download and execution time of dynamically loaded javascript files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dynamically create `script` elements and add it to the document body, set the `src` property to your javascript file and then let it download it. When the download finished, the `promise` will resolve and the next dependent js file will be set.

```js
function setExternalScript(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
       scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
       scriptTag.src = src;
       scriptTag.onload = () => resolve();
       document.appendChild(document.body, scriptTag);
  });
}

async function afterLoaded() {
    const scripts = ['a.js','b.js','c.js'];
    for(let i=0; i< scripts.length; i++)
       await setExternalScripts(scripts[i]);
}

afterLoaded(); // run this whenever you need
```

Comment: This works well, except I had to do: `document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);`

Answer (score 2):

> What I want to achieve is start loading all of these assets when page is fully loaded.

Then just move these assets at the end of your page:

```
<body>
  Some cool content
  <script src="library.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="page.bundle.js"> </script>
</body>
```

> I just need to run library.min.js then page.bundle.js in the exact order but when I need to.

Then put them in that order onto the page. You can also add the `async` and `defer` flag to defer the downloading. ([Read on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script))

> how can I split downloading and executing time of dynamically loaded javascript files?

For sure you can but why? If the js is downloaded, why not just run it directly?

> Currently I am planning to use xhr and eval content when I need it.

In the very very rare case that you need to load additional javascript (e.g. a page with some minigames, were you load the game script when the user chooses one of them), just add the script to the body:

```
 function withScript(url, callback) {
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.src = url;
   script.onload = callback;
}

withScript("additional.js", function() {
  additional.start();
});
```

Comment: You are right but I have an interesting requirement. HTML content is quite dynamic. I am trying to implement BigPipe so everything is being trasfered as chunks so I can't guarentee the order. Some fragments are so much important that needs to run immidietaly. So the location of this library.min.js is dynamic. I can't put it into end of body for all scenarios. Yes I can use server side rendering to inject into right location. But is it possible to use javascript to download it then execute it when I need it. If there is no way to do this, I will accept your answer and return to ssr method.

Comment: @ahmet for sure you can use a js loader but I don't think that the scripts load faster if you add more ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery with your project, then you can use get the script which is ajax callback. The script is executed in the global context, so it can refer to other variables and use jQuery functions. Included scripts can have some impact on the current page. Its Success Callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed. You can find a working example https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getscript.asp

For multiple script loading, you can use following code:

```
$.getMultiScripts = function(arr, path) {
var _arr = $.map(arr, function(scr, i) {
    var source = (path || "") + scr;
    updatePreloader(i, arr.length);
    return $.getScript(source);
});

_arr.push($.Deferred(function(deferred) {
    $(deferred.resolve);
}));

return $.when.apply($, _arr);
}

var prereqArray = [ "model/Lab.js", "controller/init/main.js" ];
function getEngineStarter(id) {

$.getMultiScripts(prereqArray, rPath).done(function() {
   console.log("Horray all loaded").

});

}
```